# Mockito-inline is not mocking objects

Tags: mocking, java-17

I want to mock static methods, hence used dependency "mockito-inline" with that
the static method mocks work fine but my old tests that uses mocked objects ( Mockito.mock(Sample.class)) failed as objects are failed to be mocked

Reverting to using mockito-core solves the issue but then I would not be able to mock static methods

Is there any way we can resolve this issue?

dependencies i am using

```
  testImplementation group: 'org.mockito', name: 'mockito-core', version:'3.4.4'

  testImplementation group: 'org.mockito', name: 'mockito-inline', version: '4.11.0'
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: You should post a code sample that you're using. It's not clear what can be wrong without it

Comment: Hi @SergiiBishyr thanks for commenting, i am facing the issue mentioned  here https://github.com/mockito/mockito/issues/2253,